# Issue with following client server program in Java

Tags: java, sockets, user-interface, server, client

I have coded the following code for Client Server program in Java, client and server are running on different machines and the server is running fine, but the client starts running for sometime and then terminates, there's no error in both the codes, also tried with IP address and ports, it ran only for a single time in beginning. Kindly help!!

The server code is:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
class Server
{
    ServerSocket server;
    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader br;
    PrintWriter out;
    //Constructor..
    public Server()
    {
        try {
            server=new ServerSocket(56473);
            System.out.println("Server is ready to accept connection!");
            System.out.println("Waiting...");
            socket=server.accept();

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket. getOutputStream());

            startReading();
            startWriting();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void startReading()
    {
        //will read and deliver the thread
        Runnable r1=()->{
            System.out.println("Reader Started...");
            try{
            while(true)
            {
                String msg= br.readLine();
                if(msg.equals("exit"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Client terminated the chat!");
                    socket.close();
                    break;
                }
                    System.out.println("Client: "+ msg);                
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Connection Closed!");
        }
        };
        new Thread(r1).start();
    }

    public void startWriting()
    {
        Runnable r2=()->{
            System.out.println("Writer Started....");
            try{
            while(!socket.isClosed())
            {
                BufferedReader br1= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String content=br1.readLine();
                out.println(content);
                out.flush();
                if(content.equals("exit"))
                {
                    socket.close();
                    break;
                }
            }
         } catch(Exception e){
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Connection Closed!");
        }
    };
        new Thread(r2).start();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This is Server...Going to start Server!");
        new Server();
    }
}
```

And the client code is as follows:

```
import java.net.*;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.*;

public class Client extends JFrame {

    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader br;
    PrintWriter out;

    //Declare components
    private JLabel heading = new JLabel("Client Area");
    private JTextArea messageArea= new JTextArea();
    private JTextField messageInput= new JTextField();
    private Font font= new Font("Roboto",Font.PLAIN,20);

    //constructor
    public Client()
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("Sending Request to Server");
            socket= new Socket("192.168.43.245",56473);
            System.out.println("Connection Done!");

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket. getOutputStream());


            createGUI();
            handleEvents();
            startReading();
            //startWriting();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    private void handleEvents()
    {
       messageInput.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //System.out.println("Key Released! "+e.getKeyCode());
            if(e.getKeyCode() == 10) {
                //System.out.println("You have pressed Enter Button");
                String contentToSend=messageInput.getText();
                messageArea.append("Me :"+contentToSend+"\n");
                out.println(contentToSend);
                out.flush();
                messageInput.setText("");
                messageInput.requestFocus();
            }
        }
        
       });
    }

    private void createGUI()
    {
        //GUI code..
        this.setTitle("Client Messenger[END]");
        this.setSize(700,700);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);

        //coding for component
        heading.setFont(font);
        messageArea.setFont(font);
        messageInput.setFont(font);
        heading.setIcon(new ImageIcon("clogo.jpg"));
        heading.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        heading.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        heading.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        heading.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
        messageArea.setEditable(false);
        messageInput.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        //setting the layout
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.add(heading,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JScrollPane jScrollPane= new JScrollPane(messageArea);
        this.add(jScrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(messageInput,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }


    //starts reading[METHOD]
    public void startReading()
    {
        //will read and deliver the thread
        Runnable r1=()->{
            System.out.println("Reader Started...");
            try{
            while(true)
            {
                String msg= br.readLine();
                if(msg.equals("exit"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Server terminated the chat!");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Server Terminated the Chat!");
                    messageInput.setEnabled(false);
                    socket.close();
                    break;
                }
                    //System.out.println("Server: "+ msg);
                    messageArea.append("Server : " + msg+"\n"); 
            }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Connection Closed!");
            }
        };
        new Thread(r1).start();
    }

    //starts writing[METHOD]
    public void startWriting()
    {
        Runnable r2=()->{
            System.out.println("Writer Started...");
            try{
            while(!socket.isClosed())
            {
                    BufferedReader br1= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                    String content=br1.readLine();
                    out.println(content);
                    out.flush();
                    if(content.equals("exit"))
                {
                    socket.close();
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Connection is Closed!");
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        };
        new Thread(r2).start();
    }

     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This is Client...");
        new Client();
    }
    
}
```

I expect a GUI window at client side to open but the program is terminating after sometime.

Comment: You have a try-catch block in your client that swallows all exceptions silently, so of course you haven't got any error messages. Fix your exception handling and then try again.

Comment: Your code doesn't really make a lot of sense in some areas: why are you opening a `Reader` on `System.in` in a loop. And why are you reading `System.in` *at all* if you have a gui?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk  could you please suggest some changes in the code that are relevant

Comment: @g00se could you please suggest some changes in the code that are relevant

Comment: If you've got a gui app, you need to send data to the other side via a gui component, not via stdin